# Will calling DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async multiple times create multiple threads?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm relatively new to programming in Swift for iOS. I was wondering if I do:

```
for n in 1...10 {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        sleep(5)
        print("Hello world!")
    }
}
```

Will this spawn `10` more background threads that will immedietly start working on my task?

Or will there ever only be `1` background thread and I will have just enqueued `10` things to do?

Comment: You could print `Thread.current` inside your async block and get an idea of what happens.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez `experimental_results != theoretical_guaranteed` Thanks for the suggestion, but I already tried that. The answer I'm looking for is more along the lines of what iOS assures me as a developer - and how that has changed between the different versions from the past.

Comment: Did you try looking at the documentation then? The docs for [DispatchQueue](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqueue) have your answer on the first paragraph of the Overview.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez Thanks for the link. I'm not sure which part of that documentation answers my question, though? The documentation does not make any claim to the exact number of threads created when calling `DispatchQueue.global` multiple times. Could you point to the specific clause that addresses this post, please?

Comment: As comments below mentioned, you have no guarantee to use the same thread if you are calling anything else except main thread. If you want to be sure to use the same background thread I recommend creating your own thread with identifier , example here:  [link](https://betterprogramming.pub/discovering-which-dispatchqueue-a-method-is-running-on-c0d190747078)

Comment: WWDC 2015 had a talk called [Building Responsive and Efficient Apps with GCD](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/718/) which goes into some detail about how over-using a dispatch queue can lead to a thread explosion. I would recommend watching the whole thing, but the pertinent part starts at 29:45

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating 10 tasks but the order is not guaranteed. Global returns a concurrent queue so the tasks are executed maybe at the same time maybe out of order or maybe in order. Additionally, you are in no control of the actual threads. The system uses the threads available; so if task 9 finished first, then task 10 may get the thread that task 9 had. Dispatch Apis were meant to take a lot of thread work away from the programmer. In fact even on a serial queue you couldn't guarantee the threads used by the system here. The main queue guarantees the thread, but that's the only way I know of. As for the number of threads working, the system will decide, in this case with a low priority to do as many at once as it can. (.background)

Comment: To clarify, my code will cause the iOS operating system to spawn between `1-10` threads. Minimum `1` thread. Maximum `10` threads. But the order of execution and number of threads is not guaranteed - since the system makes a decision based on resources available at that time (and treats each task as a singular detached event). Right?

Comment: I'll also add you still have the option of using threads. GCD is just an option meant to make multithreading easier on the developer.

Comment: So yeah kinda. I mean it treats it as a task (block\closure) if ten threads were running idle it could certainly use 10 threads. I you had a lot of other tasks happening say with a high qos(say: userInteractive), the system would give maybe a thread after 30 threads have been cleared. Or if it's efficient could give your app 10 additional threads waiting to execute. At any rate it is up to the system to choose how the work is distributed among threads. As for the queue, that would be something you wouldn't want to create in excess. For instance you wouldn't want 10 queues for 10 objs

Answer (score 4):

From the [DispatchQueue docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqueue):

> Work submitted to dispatch queues executes on a pool of threads managed by the system. Except for the dispatch queue representing your app's main thread, the system makes no guarantees about which thread it uses to execute a task.

> When a task scheduled by a concurrent dispatch queue blocks a thread, the system creates additional threads to run other queued concurrent tasks.

The system may use one of the existing threads, or it may create a new one. No guarantees that two work items executed on the same dispatch queue will be executed on the same thread (unless it's the main queue).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you know if there is a `minimum` or `maximum` number of threads that iOS spawns? Or is this just a secret that is dependent on the model of the device itself?

Comment: It is independent of device, however, if you want to limit the number of tasks you can. In this case it can in theory limit the number of threads. Are you trying to ultimately limit memory usage consumed by the tasks?